# Septic system in soil with clay layer

Tags: plumbing

Is a layer of clay at appx 24" down going pose a significant problem installing a septic system? It seems to be appx 24" to 30" thick. Or should we look for better conditions upslope on a 10ac lot in eastern OK.

Comment: How long and how many lay lines do you plan on running ?  And at what depth?

Comment: I was considering an infiltrator system but don't think it will work. A drip and gravel can be as large as needed. Two bedroom cabin. I really want avoid getting pumps and such involved, just a gravity flow system.

Comment: can you go deeper? clay is not conducive to a drain field (leach field, depending upon what part of the country you are in).   You should hire a septic designer who can do the appropriate field tests (perk holes) to see what will work. He/she would also be familiar with local regulations.   You want to get this right, it's a major PITA to have to fix later.

Comment: Yes, I need to get someone on it so if we have to back fill it's got a couple of years to settle. Guess I'll go upslope and dig some test holes and hope for better conditions. Thank you for your input.

Comment: @GeorgeAnderson OP says it goes down to 30” ...

Answer (score 1):

the idea with a modern septic system is that the evapotranspiration bed uses up all the waste water so that none goes into the ground water. so deep clay will not be a problem, the water is supposed to ultimately go into the atmosphere, not into the ground.

Comment: If what you are referring to is a Glendon System that isn't a gravity fed system which the OP wanted.  I have a Glendon and it involves pumps, floats, a control box.  The discharge into the Glendon pods needs to be carefully controlled and metered out. Not conducive to a gravity fed system.  Hope this helps.  Terminology and approved systems varies a lot across the country.